# Motioneyeos and Raspbian from a single SD card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I am new to Raspberry Pi and this may be a really basic question:

I have installed Raspbian on micro SD.  All smooth and I get to the desktop.

Now I want to install Motioneyeos, but when I flash Motioneyeos onto the SD card it overwrites the OS.  I only have one SD slot, how am I supposed to run OS and Motioneyeos off a single SD card?  Do I need to buy an SD card extension?  Or can I partition the SD card?

Comment: Two separate SD cards is the simplest and cleanest solution (assuming by motioneye you mean motioneyeos). The Sd card is like the hard drive in a laptop so writing an image to the SD card is like formatting and reinstalling windows on a laptop (it will erase anything that was on it). Berry boot may work to install both OS's but I have not tried it and can't say if motioneyeOS is supported by berryboot.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRobillard.  Yes I meant motioneyeos.  So with only one SD slot sounds like I will need an extender of some form to slot both into.

Comment: How do you plan to run two OS simultaneously?

Comment: I have figured out that with MotioneyesOS I don't need Raspbian OS itself, so no need for  two OSs nor for two SD slots - thanks for your suggestions.  It works well now...

Answer (score 1):

why would you need 2 SD slots if you can run 1 OS at the time?
but another solution: install all motion packages needed on Raspberry Pi OS - then you will have both: full OS (raspberry OS) and motion application
configuration can be an issue if you are new nevertheless